How to merge coverage reports (.dat) from multiple tests in Bazel
If I have run the unique C++ test with different data fed in. How can I merge .dat reports for each run of test?
I can generate C++ code coverage reports (.dat file) in Bazel through:
bazel coverage //tests --instrumentation_filter="^..."

This generates an overall coverage report for the filtered path. And I can transform the .dat report into .html files by genhtml.
However, I have to feed my test with multiple sets of data though the test itself does not need to be modified. Worse still, I cannot separate the test into multiple tests loading different datasets due to some reasons.

Well, I have got a solution with lcov:
lcov -a ${path_of_dat_file_1} -a ${path_of_dat_file_2} ... -o merged_report.dat

The lcov can merge the .dat reports into one .dat report. And then we can get the .html report with:
genhtml merged_report.dat -o ${output_folder_path}


Ah...if the ".dat" file is really an lcov-generated coverage DB (which lcov calls a ".info" file) - then yeah...lcov -o aggregate.dat -a ... will do the needful.
If you have a moderately recent lcov release, then:

you can name the directory (directories) which you want to merge rather than the coverage files themselves.  lcov will find all the coverage DBs in the directory subtree, and aggregate them.
you can pass multiple coverage files (and/or directories) to genhtml directly - and it will merge internally.  (Save a step, if you don't need to retain the aggregate DB)


genhtml is reading lcov-format coverage data files.
lcov knows how to merge files, and genhtml from moderately recent lcov releases knows how to merge coverage DBs, if passed more than one.
See the lcov and genhtml man pages, at https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov.
Exactly how to get either of those to happen from within bazel:  I don't know.

Thanks. But I need to learn how to track the coverage reports from multiple tests. However, since Bazel deletes the intermediate files (such as .info files), I can only access the .dat reports. Do you know how to merge the .dat files?
